# Haskell taking in two list with a int and returning a tuple

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell and saw a exercise which says

Write   two different   Haskell functions   having  the same    type:
`[a] -> [b] -> Int -> (a,b)`

So from my understanding the expressions should take in two lists, an int and return a tuple of the type of the lists.

What i tried so far was

```
together :: [a] -> [b] -> Int -> (a,b)
together [] [] 0 = (0,0)
together [b] [a] x = if x == a | b then (b,a) else (0,0)
```

I know I am way off but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to make your mind up what the function should return. That is *partly* determined by the signature. But still you can come up with a lot of functions that return different things, but have the same signature.

Here one of the most straightforward functions is probably to return the elements that are placed on the index determined by the third parameter.

It makes no sense to return `(0,0)`, since `a` and `b` are not per se numerical types. Furthermore `if x == a | b` is not semantically valid. You can write this as `x == a || x == b`, but this will not work, since `a` and `b` are not *per se* `Int`s.

We can implement a function that returns the heads of the two lists in case the index is `0`. In case the index is negative, or at least one of the two lists is exhausted, then we can raise an error. I leave it as an exercise what to do in case the index is greater than `0`:

```
together :: [a] -> [b] -> Int -> (a,b)
together [] _ = error "List exhausted"
together _ [] = error "List exhausted"
together (a:_) (b:_) 0 = (a, b)
together (a:_) (b:_) n | n < 0 = error "Negative index!"
                       | …
```

you thus still need to fill in the `…`.

Answer (score 4):

I generally dislike those "write any function with this signature"-type excercises precisely because of how arbitrary they are. You're supposed to figure out a definition that would make sense for that particular signature and implement it. In a lot of cases, you can wing it by ignoring as many arguments as possible:

```
fa :: [a] -> [b] -> Int -> (a,b)
fa (a:_) (b:_) _ = (a,b)
fa _ _ _ = error "Unfortunately, this function can't be made total because lists can be empty"
```

The  error here is the important bit to note. You attempted to go around that problem by returning `0`s, but this will only work when `0` is a valid value for types of `a` and `b`. Your next idea could be some sort of a "Default" value, but not every type has such a concept. The key observation is that without *any* knowledge about a type, in order to produce a value from a function, you need to get this value from somewhere else first*.

If you actually wanted a more sensible definition, you'd need to think up a use for that `Int` parameter; maybe it's the nth element from each 
list? With the help of `take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` and `head :: [a] -> a` this should be doable as an excercise.

Again, your idea of comparing `x` with `a` won't work for all types; not every type is comparable with an `Int`. You might think that this would make generic functions awfully limited; that's the point where you typically learn about how to express certain expectations about the types you get, which will allow you to operate only on certain subsets of all possible types.

---

<sup>*</sup> That's also the reason why `id :: a -> a` has only one possible implementation.

Comment: More interesting are the exercises that ask you to write the *only* function that can be implemented with a certain type.

Comment: @chepner: this is what [djinn](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/) aims to automate :).

Comment: `id :: a -> a` has only one possible *reasonable* implementation, and lots and lots of not so reasonable others.

Comment: @WillNess, I only count 3 (denotationally), unless you are counting different `error` messages as different.

Comment: @luqui yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Surely `(!!)` is even more useful to get the n-th element from a list?

Answer (score 0):

> Write two different Haskell functions having the same type:
>
> ```
> [a] -> [b] -> Int -> (a,b)
> ```

As Willem and Bartek have pointed out, there's a lot of gibberish functions that have this type.

Bartek took the approach of picking two based on what the simplest functions with that type could look like. One was a function that did nothing but throw an error. And one was picking the first element of each list, hoping they were not empty and failing otherwise. This is a somewhat theoretical approach, since you probably don't ever want to *use* those functions in practice.

Willem took the approach of suggesting an actually useful function with that type and proceeded to explore how to exhaust the possible patterns of such a function: For lists, match the empty list `[]` and the non-empty list `a:_`, and for integers, match some stopping point, `0` and some categories `n < 0` and `…`.

A question that arises to me is if there is any other equally useful function with this type signature, or if a second function would necessarily have to be hypothetically constructed. It would seem natural that the `Int` argument has some relation to the positions of elements in `[a]` and `[b]`, since they are also integers, especially because a pair of single `(a,b)` is returned.

But the only remotely useful functions (in the sense of not being completely silly) that I can think of are small variations of this: For example, the `Int` could be the position from the end rather than from the beginning, or if there's not enough elements in one of the lists, it could default to the last element of a list rather than an error. Neither of these are very pleasing to make ("from the end" conflicts with the list being potentially infinite, and having a fall-back to the last element of a list conflicts with the fact that lists don't necessarily have a last element), so it is tempting to go with Bartek's approach of writing the simplest useless function as the second one.

Comment: FWIW, I meant `fa` as one function with two definitions, but now that you wrote your answer, I suppose you could treat that as two distinct functions.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose it doesn't really matter.